# Maintaining the session even after the browser is closed

Tags: session, session-state, session-timeout

Could anyone tell how to maintain a session (in PHP) so that the session contains are preserved and are accessible even after the browser is restarted.

In general a session expires with the closing of a browser, but I want the session `NOT TO BE CLOSED` so that the session data's can be accessed the next time the browser is used.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really good tutorial on [howto save session contents to a database](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/session-handler.html).
The only thing needed is to refill a new session with the saved data - there you go.

Answer (score 1):

Store session data somewhere in a DB and keep session ID in an encrypted persistent HTTP-only cookie.

Comment: could you explain it a little bit more ? It would be better